# Questions regarding Goku's special training as shown in episode 71 of Dragon Ball Super

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In epsiode 71 of Dragon Ball Super, Goku is shown to have some kind of special training. It seems that Whis knows what Goku is doing but doesn't want to tell Vegeta.

My questions are:

1. What is the special training that Goku is currently undergoing?
2. Why doesn't Whis tell Vegeta about this?
3. Why Beerus says that "Goku is the leading fighter..." even though till the last fight (i.e., with Zamasu) both seemed to be on equal level?
4. Does it mean that Goku is again going to get stronger than Vegeta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We don't know whether Goku is undergoing a special training or not. Perhaps he do, but it's just speculation.
2. There is a rumor about either Whis or Vados hired Hit to assassinate Goku (I can't find the source, but it's around the internet). In the episode, Beerus is furious about the Universal Tournament promised by the Omni King, and Goku doesn't come to train. Whis might see this as an opportunity to "*train*' Goku in another way. Whis know Hit is the perfect rival for Goku besides Vegeta, since Goku can be brought back to life at the end, or Whis reverse the time when Goku is dead. If Vegeta knew about this, he definitely couldn't focus on training. It's all just my speculation, we may find out in the future episodes.
3. In the base form and in SSB form, both seems equal in power and speed. But don't forget Goku has Kaioken to multiply his power.
4. There is no "who is stronger" between Goku and Vegeta. Both are equally strong if you don't wanna trigger anyone. Sometimes Vegeta surpasses Goku and vise versa.

Comment: What does it say in the manga?

Comment: @user170039 The manga hasn't catch up with episode 71 yet.

Comment: Vegeta should be stronger in SSB form than Goku since he trained 6 months more in the hyperbolic time chamber and thanks to that he became able to overpower Goku Black. But then the series authors decided to make Goku able to hold his own against merged zamasu in an energy clash, something which doesnt make any sense unless you try to fit it with some hard to believe theory such as Goku got a stronger zenkai boost than Vegeta in his last fight for some unkwown reason. The authors should have made Goku used the kaioken in the energy clash and everything it would make more sense

Comment: @Pablo: Yes. Personally I also think that the authors have been very much partial to Goku when it comes to questions like "who is stronger between the two".

Answer (score 1):

1. Seeing as it was revealed, Goku is waiting for Hit to come at him and is constantly on edge seeing Hit can manipulate time.
2. Whis hired Hit for Goku to assassinate Goku. Seeing as Vegeta would try to stop Goku and Beerus wouldn't risk losing one of his prized (and leading) fighters, Whis decided not to tell them.
3. Goku still has his Kaioken as pointed out by Happy Face, next to that is that Beerus fought Goku and didn't fight Vegeta (also out of universe reason, Gokus is the protagonist of Dragon Ball)
4. The constant jist of Goku vs Vegeta is that they both will get powerfull than the other at a certain point in the story every time but the other will catch up and surpass the first.